# PS Query - how to generate an output that includes "current month deduction" and "YTD total deduction"?

Tags: peoplesoft

I have been tasked with generating a report in Query Manager in HRMS to create an output file that shows in one column the current month deduction and then a running YTD total deduction based on the same dedID.... is this possible?

---

Example:

ID: 123
effDt: 1/1/2016
dedAmt: $10

ID: 123
effDt: 2/1/2016
dedAmt: $15

ID: 123
effDt: 3/1/2016
dedAmt: $20

ID: 123
effDt: 4/1/2016
dedAmt: $10
(curr record)

I need my output to generate something like:

effDt: 4/1/2016  |   ID: 123  |   YTD_Ded: $55  |   Curr_ded: $10

---

Obviously, I have a list of deductionIDs that I will need to deal with... but I've been messing around with query manager for awhile now and I haven't been able to figure out how to generate this and I can ONLY use query manager... anyone have any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you use an expression for the calculated field?

Comment: turns out what we wanted to accomplish could not be done in Query Manager, so I am closing this issue... thanks for helping :)